# grep regular expression returns full line

Tags: regex, grep

Im trying to print everything after a keyword using grep but the command returns the whole line. Im using the following:

```
grep -P (\skeyword\s)(.*)
```

an example line is:

```
abcdefg         keyword   hello, how are you.
```

The result should be `hello, how are you` but instead it gives the full line. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `-o` (*only matching*) parameter and `\K` (*discards the previously matched characters*) or a positive lookbehind.

```
grep -oP '\skeyword\s+\K.*' file
```

[`\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match. `\s+` matches one or more space characters.

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'abcdefg         keyword   hello, how are you.' | grep -oP '\skeyword\s+\K.*'
hello, how are you.
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, Grep prints lines that match.  To print only matching expressions try the '-o' option.